# Is there any way to import a subset of a node library?

Tags: typescript, npm, next.js

I need to use the [typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) library in a cloud function environment which restricts the entry point function, `middleware`, to 1MB. I only need one functions from the library, but the following function is still 1.7MB.

```js
import {NextRequest, NextResponse} from "next/server";
import {DBCompilationArtifact} from "@/database/ProjectActions";
import {transpile} from "typescript";
import {DBCompilationInput} from "@/utils/ProjectUtils";


const buildCompilationArtifact = (compilationInput: DBCompilationInput): DBCompilationArtifact => {
    return {
        name: compilationInput.name,
        artifact: transpile(compilationInput.source)
    }
}

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const compilationInput = JSON.parse(req.cookies.compilationInput) as DBCompilationInput
    const compilationArtifacts = buildCompilationArtifact(compilationInput)
    console.log(compilationArtifacts)

    return NextResponse.json(compilationArtifacts)
}
```

The '@/' imports are just local interface definitions which I doubt increase the bundle size by much.

Does using:

```
import {transpile} from "typescript";
```

Instead of

```
import * from "typescript";
```

Actually reduce my bundle size, or will it include all of TS anyway?
Are there any tricks I can use to reduce the package size further?

Comment: Tools like webpack are designed to reduce your bundle to only the pieces you need. Are you using webpack or something similar?

Comment: @Evert Yes I am using Webpack5

Comment: Then given that you bring in a large project and actually use it to compile typescript, I think that bundle size is more or less what I would expect. Typescript is complex.